# Manual Index Creation APIs using Spring data elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there a way to create index manually using spring data elastic search and Java High Level Rest Client.

These are some of the api's that come to my mind which are specific to elastic index.

type is also taken as an argument because it is closely related with ES index.

```
createIndexWithCustomMappings(String indexName, String fieldMappings);
createTypeWithCustomMappings(String indexName, String type, String fieldMappings);
addAlias(String aliasName);
fetchAlias(String aliasName);
deleteIndex(String indexName);
getTypeSchema(String indexName, String type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Data Elasticsearch you will have an `ElasticsearchOperations` instance injected in your application.

```
@Autowired
ElasticsearchOperations operations;
```

You can use this to obtain a `IndexOperations` instance:

```
IndexOperations indexOperations = operations.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of("indexname"));
```

`IndexOperations` has 4 different methods to create an index, the easiest being

```
indexOperations.create();
```

There are other methods to create the index with settings and/or mappings, check the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.4/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/IndexOperations.html)